# Empty model value when happen HttpPost method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, partial-views, guid

I have partial view for deleting *user*. I use bootstrap modal popup for this action.

So my codes are as follows.

**Index.chtml**

```
    @*Inside foreach loop*@
   <div class="modal hide fade" id="Delete_@index">
         @Html.Partial("_DeleteUser", user)
   </div>
```

**_DeleteUser**

```
@model Classes.User

<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
   <h3>İstifadəçinin məlumatları</h3>
</div>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
   {
       Html.HiddenFor(user => user.UserId);
       Html.AntiForgeryToken();
       <div class="modal-body">
           <strong>Bu istifadəçini silmək istədiyinizdən əminsiniz...?</strong>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
           <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
   }
```

And my HttpPost method action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(User user)
    {
        userRepository.DeleteById(user.UserId);
        return View("User");
    }
```

After this scenario I get *{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}* type Guid value for User.UserId. Perhaps its has very easy solution, but I can not find an hour. Please help me.

**Not:** I use

```
1)Html.HiddenFor(user => user.UserId);
2)<input type="hidden" value="@Model.UserId" id="UserId"/>
```

but still not work.

**Solution:**
**It works when I move hidden inside model-body div, why it happend I don't know)), thanks a lot to everyone**

Comment: Only form inputs that have a `name` attribute are submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the source on your partial view.  I had a similar setup and result a while ago.  Found that I had to do my hidden field differently.  Using

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.UserId">
```

had the correct id where html.hiddenfor was empty.

Comment: I believe you mean `value="@Model.UserId"`.  You can also use the alternate Hidden helper that is not strongly typed, i.e. `@Html.Hidden("UserId", @Model.UserId)`.

Comment: I use  Html.HiddenFor(user => user.UserId);. But didn't work.

Comment: looking at the source does your hidden field have a value?

Comment: if it isn't being passed with the model you might try adding a name to the input tag and then on the controller calling Request.Form["UserId"] to see if you can get the id that way